# oracle trigger to update a new row of view while inserting new row in a table

Tags: database, oracle, triggers, oracle12c

Can someone help me to write a trigger on an oracle expression view x which is populating data from another table y through a select query.

The logic:
After inserting a new row in table y; when value of a new column on an inserted row in table y is 'xyz' then I want to update some columns of expression view x based on the condition 'xyz' on the new row inserted to table y.

Can someone help?

Chandra

Comment: What do you mean by an 'expression view'? If you have a view whose query refers to the table you're updating, it will see the new value anyway - you wouldn't need a trigger. If it isn't referencing that table then you could use a trigger to update a table it is referencing, though that implies the data isn't normalised. It isn't clear what you're really trying to do.

Comment: Hi  Alex, Thanks for the update, I want to write a trigger which will update 2 columns of newly inserted row on the same table with a if condition will check on another column value of the newly inserted row.

Comment: So where does the view come into it? You seem to now be referring to multiple rows in one table, rather than two tables. Edit your question to clarify what you really need to achieve; show the table definition, the view definition if there is one and it's relevant, sample starting data, the insert statement you'll run and the expected results. It may still be too broad but at the moment it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Hi Alex, I am not referring to multiple rows in the table. I have only one table suppose 'Test'. There are 4 columns A,B,C,D. When a new row will be inserted to 'Test'; the value of  column A would be in a comparison block(if condition). If the condition is true then I need to update C, D columns of the row without impacting the column  B value. All transaction will be on a new single row and single table 'Test'. Does it make any sense? I want a trigger to do this task on a new row when inserted for a single table.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understood the problem (though, more through reading comments than a question whose "expression view" made me puzzled).

That would be a trigger-based *solution*; it checks whether value entered into the A column is larger than 100 (that's your "if condition"); if so, it modifies both C and D columns. If not, it doesn't do anything.

```
SQL> create table test (a number, b number, c number, d number);

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bi_test
  2    before insert on test
  3    for each row
  4    when (new.a > 100)
  5  begin
  6    :new.c := 3;
  7    :new.d := 4;
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into test (a) values (50);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test (a) values (200);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

         A          B          C          D
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        50
       200                     3          4

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks Littlefoot. I will try this. Does this trigger work on the rows of new table or already existing table having rows on it?

What if I have more when conditions?

Comment: Trigger works only for newly added rows; existing ones aren't affected - you'd have to write another piece of code to update them. If there are more conditions, add them to WHEN clause. If you can't, there's still the good old IF-THEN-ELSE, available in PL/SQL (which trigger *is*).

Comment: Hi little foot I did the same way you said but the trigger does not work as per my requirement.  Is it fine if I elaborate you the requirement?

Comment: Sure; edit your question and post new information (just don't type it all into the comment).

Comment: Hi Littlefoot; I did the requirement implementation in a different possible way. Thanks for your valuable help.